# AngularJS - what is the best way to translate this jQuery to AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using AngularJS in order to create a directive for an accordion, I have a plugin but this plugin has some jQuery that I want to remove and translate it to Angular.

Actually this is the code that I want to translate:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    angular.forEach(scope.ngModel, function(value, key) {
      if (value.collapsed) {
        $('#' + scope.panelBaseId + '-' + key).collapse('show');
      }
    });
  });
```

what can I do with that **$(document).ready(function()...** ?

Comment: There are way more things involved when designing a directive like an accordion than just hide/show existing element by id. I suggest you look at http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion

Comment: does `ng-cloak` help?

Comment: @cleftheris I need to customize it and the angular ui plug in does not work for me.

@elaijuh what ```ng-cloak``` does in this case?

Comment: @MarkRenton - for what ng-cloak is: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak